# How does the electric potential change on the inner conductor when the outer conductor is grounded?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

The conductors are spherical (thin) shells, the inner one is off-center from the outer one. Both initially charged and neither grounded. Charge $Q_a$ at $r=a$ and $Q_b$ at $r=b$. The space between the two conductors is empty.

[image]

The outer conductor, initially having electric potential $V_b$, is then grounded. How does this affect the electric potential of the inner conductor $V_a$?

Comment: Faraday's ice pail :)

Comment: Looks interesting, will look it up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy. Before grounding, the potential difference between the inner conducting sphere and the outer conducting sphere is $V_a-V_b$. After grounding, the outer sphere has potential zero and has no charge at the outer surface while the charge and its distribution on the inner surface remains unchanged equal to $-Q_a$ as does the charge $Q_a$ on the inner sphere. Therefore, also the electric field distribution in the space between the inner and outer sphere remains constant and also the potential difference between the inner and the outer sphere remains $V_a-V_b$. Thus the potential of the inner sphere, which was $V_a$ before grounding, becomes $V_a-V_b$ after grounding.

Comment: Thanks! I had some trouble understanding why the potential difference remains the same, now it's clear. I didn't properly consider the properties of conductors, the induced charge $-Q_a$.

About the charge $Q_a$ remaining the same, this is because the inner conductor is isolated in space from other objects/ground?

Comment: @Smooth Operator - You are right! The charge $Q_a$ in the inner sphere has to stay constant, there is no reason why it should change.